# Get UGC Comments List from custom page

Tags: ugc

I need to develop a custom page in Tridion using core services, in which I need to get the list of UGC comments for a particular component i.e. tcm id of that tcm id
Can this be done using core services ? Any documentation present to get the list of UGC comments using core services ?
Or Do I need to make a REST call through custom page code to moderation service i.e. http://localhost:8087/odata.svc/Comments(Id=10002)?$filter=&$format=json , but this only has input parameter Id as Comment Id, not tcm id of component.
Any pointers how can I achieve it making a service call through custom code ?

Note - I cannot use Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC API as my custom page is on CMS side.

Is there any other approach I can adopt to get the desired list of comments for a particular component.

Your help, guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you explore the moderation service with something like https://www.linqpad.net/? You may have to expand your query to other oData Entities via the $expand parameter.

Comment: Hi Philippe, Thanks for your reply. I had a explored the service in linqpad. Now, I am able to get desired output using query - http://localhost:8083/odata.svc/Comments()?$filter=ItemId eq 11577 and ItemPublicationId eq 12&$select=Content Now, My question is Do I need to create a HttpClient object and make a REST call to this service with these 2 parameters in query to get the list of comment ? Any better  approach can you suggest.